# Open modal with javascript instead of link using a wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am using the wordpress plugin [Easy Modal](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-modal/)

I can open a modal like that `<a href="#" class="eModal-11">Open Modal</a>`. Now I want to open the modal with javascript like that

```
if (var == true) { openmodal-11(); }
```

Is there a way I can do this, without looking at the plugin code? So I can "open" the class with javascript like fake clicking on the link.. I am kind of a newbe in coding...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this page](https://easy-modal.com/documentation/easy-modal/using-easy-modal/opening-modal) which suggets it's using a normal jQuery plugin approach to interacting with the page elements, and the below should work:

```
$('#eModal-11').emodal('open');
```

Comment: Hm that didn't do the trick.. I guess I have to go through the code to figure it out

Comment: see edited answer - found a page that describes opening them programmatically

Comment: hmm that returns: TypeError: $(...).emodal is not a function

Comment: what about `jQuery('#e....` - I'm not too familiar with wordpress etc, so $ may not be available for jQuery and need to use the full name instead.

Comment: I have used the full code described on the page, now there is no error.But it is not opening though..

Comment: ok - if there's no error now it suggests it's at least found the `emodal` function.  Only thing I can suggest now is to check your classnames / IDs etc match the code

Comment: I will check and keep trying :) thank you for your effort! I will post the right solution if I will find one..

Comment: If I execute $('#eModal-11').emodal('open'); in the console.. the modal pops up.. if I use the code with ready function in the template it does not work :/

Comment: Are you adding it to any form of handler, eg on click etc?  If you're running it immediately on page load, `emodal` may not have been initialised yet

Comment: I got it working with setTimeout.. that works fine for me, since I wanted to let it popup a few seconds later anyway... Thank you for your help! Appreciate it!